# Cordova For Visual Studio Deploy Failed

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, genymotion, visual-studio-cordova

Excuse me for my english

Im trying to deploy a simple cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 Community IDE over Windows 7 32. Compilation is correct, but deploy not.

Details:

```
1>Compilación correcta. (Correct Compilation)
1>
1>Tiempo transcurrido 00:00:45.00
2>------ Operación Implementar iniciada: proyecto: BlankCordovaApp1, configuración: Debug Android ------
2>  Querying ADB for attached devices...
2>El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado (The system does not find specific file)
2>El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
========== Compilar: 1 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Implementar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

If i compile and launch the same cordova app with command line works fine:

```
C:\Cordova\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>cordova run android
```

I used Genymotion that works like a phisical device and works fine with the line. I installed SDK, Node, Java, Apache Ant by myself

Answer (score 2):

Try to check visual studio setting, Tool > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Enviroment Variables. If you install related tool by yourself, then you should check this out.

Comment: I check that variables. But i think the problem is another. VS is looking for an emuator and genymotion acts a phisical device. The query (Command) for the output window is VS: "Querying ADB for attached devices" loooks like VS is looking for an emulator. I dont have Android Emulator create with Android Studio Tools

Answer (score 0):

Ready! I set Android SDK in Tools/Xamarin/Android

Thanks friend!