# visual studio - cordova - running my app on an Android device

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have followed these instructions:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-apache/#android-devices

[image]

I have enabled USB debugging mode in my device.

And everything seems fine:

[image: adt]

Although, when i pushed the "device" button

[image]

App was built fine(apk was created) but there was an error:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: v2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>  Querying ADB for attached devices...
2>The system cannot find the file specified
2>The system cannot find the file specified
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: run adb kill-server and then adb start-server. See if the issue can be solved.

Comment: OK, didn't work =\

Comment: Go to Visual Studio-> Tools->Options->"Environment Variable Overrides"->ADT_HOME. ensure the correct android sdk path is configured

Comment: it's unchecked, but with the correct value.

Comment: Ah... Hard to believe, but worth a try. Someone encountered the same issue before and resolved by setting the Android SDK path in Xamarin setting page in VS Tools menu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406230/cordova-for-visual-studio-deploy-failed

Comment: Yep, probably not related, I don't even have this option, Xamarin is not installed at all...

Comment: Last try - run your VS as administrator. If the issue persist, I will suggest you try to use process monitor tool https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 to determine what file it is looking for and not able to find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109775/discussion-between-dorad-and-alan-yao-msft).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we chat, since I saw you were able to run the adb command in command prompt in administrator mode. So try VS as administrator may help.